# react native android 'Unable to download JS bundle'

Tags: android, windows, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run dictionary project on my samsung GT-I9100 (android 4.1.2).
I'm able to build the project and install it on the device. But when I run it, I got a red screen saying
**"Unable to download JS bundle"**
i follow this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dictionary-app-using-react-native-for-android--cms-24969) to run dictionary project. but i got error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that if you deploy your app to your Android device rather than an emulater you get a red screen of death with an error saying Unable to load JS Bundle. You need to set the debug server for your device to be your computer running react...either its name OR IP address.

Press the device Menu button
Select Dev Settings
Select Debug server host for device
Type in your machine's IP and Reload JS
More info: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

Comment: Did you put in your computers IP address and the react native port? E.g. 192.168.1.100:8081 (obviously the 192.168... IP will be substituted with your computers IP)

Comment: The only other time I've had this was to do with the version of watchman I was running.  In a new shell, run brew update then: brew unlink watchman then: brew install watchman  now, you can run react-native start from your project folder  I leave this shell open, create a new shell window and run: react-native run-android from my project folder.